# present perfect continuous vs. present continuous

Tags: present-tense, perfect-aspect, continuous-aspect, perfect-continuous

how can we differenciate present perfect continuous .
we use it for the actions which started in the past and still continuing but we start doing the exam in present continuous tense.
I am working on the project.
I have been working on the project.